# How to save output from matplotlib 3d plot in the form of an interactive figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am using MPL toolkit to plot a 3d projection in python3 environment. I am able to visualize a nice interactive 3D scatter plot with this code

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(dimension1, dimension2, dimension3, c='r', marker='o') 
plt.show()
```

Whenever I want to visualize my data, I need to run above script. I am wondering is there any way I can save this interactive 3d plot for sharing it with others or a quick review?

I found similar questions and most of the answer suggests to use `pickle`, but again I need to open the pickle  file using a python script! But I am looking for something which can be useful to save 3D plot as an interactive image.

Comment: Would a 3d animation be good enough, or does it have to be interactive?

Comment: You necessarily need python to show a matplotlib figure interactively. (Similar to how you need a pdf reader to view a pdf file). Maybe your best bet is to share a link to a webpage which has python running server-side?

Comment: @StephenMeschke 3d animation would be good i guess. Any pointers on how to create a 3d animation or a gif for the same?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will look into that. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, so if an animation is enough, [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/random_walk.html) is how to create an animation,  [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html) is how you save one as mp4, change to `ani.save("movie.gif", writer="imagemagick")` for animated gif. In total that would probably be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344934/animate-a-rotating-3d-graph-in-matplotlib).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your response. I will try it out.