# Plotting multiple 3d scatterplots with matplotlib using same data but different viewing angles without scattering data for each subplot individually

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, subplot, scatter

I am trying to create a figure containing 3 subplots with 3d-scatterplots. All the scatterplots contain the same data, but I want to plot them using different azimuthal angle and elevation as is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904912/how-to-set-camera-position-for-3d-plots-using-python-matplotlib).

Because I have a large dataset, I would like to scatter the data only once instead of for every subplot individually and then use

```
ax.view_init(elev=XX., azim=YY)
```

on each subplot separately.

Is there a way to 'share the scatter data between subplots'?

This is more or less how I imagine the code to work:

- read in data
- create 3 empty subplots
- scatter the data for first subplot
- copy scattered data for second and third subplot
- apply different angles with ax.view_init()

Comment: Why don't want to issue the scatter drawing command for each subplot? What's the problem with that?

Comment: It works, but it takes too long. I have millions of points to scatter, and every scatter takes a few minutes. I would like to speed that up by not re-scattering everything again.