# Removing background on a 3d plot Julia

Tags: matplotlib, grid, julia, plots.jl

I am having some real trouble trying to plot nice things with Julia. 
I first used PyPlot which I was happy with but I had to be able to change the angle on a 3D plots (in that case using surface) so I now use Plots directly with the camera speficication. I would like to remove the background on a 3D plot.

using PyPlot, the following command :

> ax=gca();  ax:set_axis_off

works fine. 
When using Plots, I tried the following :

> using Plots; pyplot(grid=false)

and then my code for the surface, and it does not change the output. 
I also tried the first example on this page :https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/pull/695 and grid specification does not work (grids are the same on every area of the layout).

I tried after updating every package and it still does not work.

Does anyone have an idea about what would the problem be please?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I think this is not yet possible with Plots.jl. I asked the same thing a couple of weeks ago: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/removing-axes-in-plots-jl-3d-plot/9104/2

Comment: But you can of course change the angle on a 3D plot with PyPlot/matplotlib, see e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904912/how-to-set-camera-position-for-3d-plots-using-python-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally did it using PyPlot but I liked the @layout property of Plots that is a bit more handy than using subplot with PyPlot. Although now I have an other problem is the colormap property that does not work using PyPlot, producing surfaces of one color only... Work in progress.. thank you