# How to plot a 3D histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I have three arrays and I am trying to make a 3D histogram.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 8, 6, 7]
y = [10, 10, 20, 50, 20, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 60]
z = [105, 25, 26, 74, 39, 85, 74, 153, 52, 98]
```

Here's my attempt so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

binsOne = sorted(set(x))
binsTwo = sorted(set(y))
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[binsOne, binsTwo])
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25 , yedges[:-1] + 0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)

dx = dx.flatten()
dy = dy.flatten()
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
```

How do I incorporate the z array into my 3D histogram?

Comment: I advice you this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611716/wrong-overlab-in-bar3d-plot
Matplotlib have some issues with the 3D plotting, so pay attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z` array must have the same shape not of `x` and `y` but of `xpos` and `ypos` (which are of themselves the same shape). You may find [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html) more useful than the one you appear to be [drawing from](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html). The following code is to demonstrate the example in the first link applied to your question,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

_x = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 8, 6, 7]
_y = [10, 10, 20, 50, 20, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50]
_xx, _yy = np.meshgrid(_x, _y)
x, y = _xx.ravel(), _yy.ravel()
_z = np.array([105, 25, 26, 74, 39, 85, 74, 153, 52, 98])

# There may be an easier way to do this, but I am not aware of it
z = np.zeros(len(x))
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    z[i] = _z[(i*len(_z)) / len(x)]

bottom = np.zeros_like(z)
width = depth = 1

ax.bar3d(x, y, bottom, width, depth, z, shade=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, why is the z not following x and y in ax.bar3d? Also can you explain to me what does the for loop does for _z?

Comment: @Matt-pow I don't understand your question, the `z` values in the array are determining the height of the the bar, the `x` values determine the `x` position and the `y` values determine the `y` position. For `x` and `y` pairs that correspond to a common `z` value you see multiple bars. The values on the `y` and `x` axis are a little confusing since the bar `1` in `x` actually goes from `1` to `2` and `8` goes from `8` to `9`.

Comment: @Matt-pow The `for` loop for `_z`  converts `_z`, a shape `(10L, )` array into `z` a shape `(100L, )` array populated by 10 instances of each value

Comment: Thanks for the explaination