# How to download 3d plots with a specific camera angle in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

I am using jupyter ipython notebook to generate 3d plots using matplotlib. I can get zoom and and pan options with the `%matplotlib notebook` command. I would like to download the plots with a specific camera angle that I choose with the pan/rotate option. Using `savefig` saves the default camera angle of the plot. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set "camera position" for 3d plots using python/matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904912/how-to-set-camera-position-for-3d-plots-using-python-matplotlib)

Comment: `savefig` should save the figure in its currently active state. Of course `savefig` should be called only once the zooming and panning is finished. If that is not the case for you, you might want to show a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the mouse to the up right-hand side of the plot, some options show up. If you press the first one (with the shape of a camera), it will save your plot with your desired angle to the download folder of your laptop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).