# Visualization of 3D vector using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize two 3D column vectors using matplotlib.
Here are the vector

```
v1 = (0, 2 , 1)
v2 = (2, 2, 0)
```

The visualization for the above vectors that I got from the book.
[image]

[Source: Introduction to Linear Algebra, Fifth Edition (2016), by Gilbert Strang ]

I am trying to to visualize the same. Here is code and the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

soa = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0.5, 0.7, 0]])

X, Y, Z, U, V, W = zip(*soa)
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)
ax.set_xlim([-1, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 5])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 8])
plt.show()
```

View:
[image]

I am not sure about the view. is it correct? Need help if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line:

```
soa = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0.5, 0.7, 0]])
```

you are defining 4 3D vectors, 3 of which have 0 length, the last one starts from `(0, 0, 4)` and has components `(0.5, 0.7, 0)`. So the code is compliant with the image you reported.
If you want to plot the vectors `v1` and `v2`, both starting from origin, you should use:

```
soa = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]])
```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

soa = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]])

X, Y, Z, U, V, W = zip(*soa)
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)
ax.set_xlim([-1, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 5])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 8])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. By mistake I copied different code. But Now I know the answer.

Comment: do you have any idea to set this view (without rotating by hand manually) by code only ?

Comment: Try to take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905458/9214357)