# Aligning camera in Matplotlib to match known projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I have a rendered image which contains a set of 8 alignment points (a unit cube). I would like to use these points to get a matching set of Matplotlib 3D axes which match the view of the image, i.e. where the projected coordinates of the cube in my image line up with the coordinates of a unit cube plotted in the 3D matplotlib plot. Is there a good way of approaching this problem? It appears just setting the view (az and elev) is not sufficient, as the camera looks at the center of the plots box which doesn’t necessarily align with the way it is in my image?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904912/how-to-set-camera-position-for-3d-plots-using-python-matplotlib/12905458#12905458

Comment: Please provide an example.